# Why Oracle objects return "???" for every text attribute?

Tags: java, oracle10g

I wrote a procedure returning a plain object, having all the attributes declared as VARCHAR2. My java code, after executing the procedure, read these objectes and all I see is three question marks "???" instead of text. It seems it may be an NLS_LANG problem, but I'm not really sure.

Is this an NLS_LANG problem? How can I resolve this?

NOTE: The Java 1.5 app is querying a Oracle 10g DB.

Comment: It might better illustrate the issue better if you could include the procedure (or representative snippet) and a 'desc' of the table; also if you suspect an NLS_LANG type issue - can you get the current value of this setting, and also if on *nix do a 'locale -a' / 'env' to check OS settings...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using international characters with Oracle object types, you need to include the `orai18n.jar` which can be downloaded at the same place as the driver itself.

From the driver's readme file:

> *orai18n.jar: It contains classes for NLS support in Oracle Object and Collection types.*

Comment: In my case, we have a Weblogic server running the app. The connection to Oracle database is done by datasource, so orai18n.jar has been added to Weblogic classpath (in a windows installation setDomainEnv.cmd file has been edited to add to CLASSPATH variable the path to orai18n.jar, usuarlly WEBLOGIC/server/ext/jdbc/oracle/10g/orai18n.jar).

Answer (score 2):

Seems like unicode issue, try getting your  Database Character Set by:

```
Select value from SYS.NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS where PARAMETER = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET'
```

Should the problem still exist i suggest you take a look at [Unicode support with Oracle](http://www.advancedquerytool.com/help/907.htm)